# Input Textbox to string variable

Tags: c#, variables

I have a form with an input box. I am trying to work out how to send the value entered in that text box to a variable pre-declared globally in a class above as:

```
GlobalVars.variable ="";
```

Below is my text box:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox f2inputTextBox1;
this.f2inputTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
```

How do I then assign this to a `GlobalVars.variable`?

Comment: This seems ill-advised. It really would help if you explained what you want to do with `GlobalVars.variable`.

Comment: ...are you adding `f2inputTextBox1` to your Form's `Controls()` collection?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `variable` property is a string, you'd want to take the `text` value of the textbox.

```
GlobalVars.variable = this.f2inputTextBox1.text
```

That said, the concept of having a global variable is suspicious at best. You may want to reconsider the structure of your code to avoid things like global variables.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would advise against assigning directly to a variable in another class. Change instead into a public property and do it as follows:

```
GlobalVars.Property = f2inputTextBox.Text
```